# Is it possible to allow non SSL for certain Subfolders in Apache-Config

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https

I have an small online shop. For security reasons I force every http-request to be https with this code in the apache-config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #Redirects http:// to https://
    Redirect permanent / https://www.website.de/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfectly fine. But now ebay forces me to deliver images with http and not https (what would be no problem for security).

All the pictures are in the subfolder www.website.de/media/. Is there any possibility to allow http and https for this subfolder?

Already thanks to the community.
Regards Timo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now done it with an small workaround: The webshop supports different domains for static and dynamic content. So I just created a subdomain static.website.de which can deliver static content https and http.

This only works with system which supports different Domains for static content. Magento does this. Hope this helps some of you :).